# Visual Studio Tools for Cordova - Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My Cordova app has been building fine for weeks, and then all of a sudden the build is failing - I'm targeting the VS Emulator for Android, and my Cordova Tools has the latest update.

```
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
1>  Reading build config file: .. build.json
1>  Running: ...\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b ...\platforms\android\build.gradle -  Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
1>  :preBuild
1>  :compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
1>  :preDebugBuild
1>  :checkDebugManifest
1>  :CordovaLib:compileLint
1>  :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:preBuild
1>  :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
1>  :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
1>  :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
1>  :prepareDebugDependencies
1>  :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
1>  :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :mergeDebugAssets FAILED
1>
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>  * What went wrong:
1>  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
1>  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Comment: Can you try to build a default blank app? (basic trouble shooting technique to know if the problem is in the tools or in your project). I will also try to "Clean"

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to run on an actual device when getting this error but the solution for me was to simply do a clean. For me it was "clean android --device" After that I was able to deploy to my device without getting this error.

Comment: similarly for the same error in an android studio project, Build/Clean before trying to run the project worked to fix the error.